# What is the proof for the conditions of a normal approximation of the binomial distribution: $np > 5$ and $n(1 - p) > 5$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

For a normal approximation of the binomial to be valid,

$np > 5$

$n(1 - p) > 5$

What is the *algebraic* proof for this and where does the $5$ come from?

Comment: There is no proof. I imagine that beyond, the global error is very acceptable,  less, say, than 1%.

Comment: A very interesting article on this subject is here: http://stochastik-in-der-schule.de/sisonline/struktur/jahrgang21-2001/heft1/2001-1_Eich.pdf Beware, it's written in German.

Comment: Interestingly enough, that article seems to refer to a different rule of thumb, namely that the approximation is *sufficiently accurate* when $np (1 - p) \gt 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JeanMarie Comments, *there is no proof.* This is a very rough rule-of-thumb. I suppose it survives
because it is considered 'easier to remember' than better criteria. (And it is a little
better if you use 10 instead of 5.)
You can see a discussion of several better 'rules' in the Wilipedia
article on 'binomial distribution' under *normal approximation.*

Especially
for small $n,$ a major consideration is that normal approximation
to normal works best for $p$ near 1/2, so that the binomial is
nearly symmetrical, and thus easier to approximate with the 
symmetrical normal.

One of the easiest to remember of the better rules is to have both
$np/q > 9$ and $nq/p > 9,$ where
$q = 1-p.$ This ensures that binomial values in $[0,n]$ correspond
to standard normal values in $(-3,3)$.

With the current wide availability of statistical software, there is
seldom a reason in practice to use a normal approximation.
For example, if $X \sim Binom(100, 0.1),$ then the exact
value of $P(X \le 5) = 0.0576$ can be obtained in R statistical
software as follows:

```
pbinom(5, 100, .1)
## 0.05757689
```

But about the most accurate normal approximation with the usual
method (including continuity correction) is 0.0668, obtained by:

```
n = 100;  p = .1;  q = 1-p
mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*q)
pnorm(5.5, mu, sg)
## 0.0668072
```

Generally, it is not prudent to expect more than two-place
accuracy for a normal approximation, although there are even cases that
violate rules of thumb and still give surprisingly good results. Consider
$P(X = 2) = P(1.5 < X \le 2.5) = 3/8 = 0.3750,$ with $X \sim Binom(3, 1/2)$.
The normal approximation with continuity correction gives 0.3759.

```
n = 3;  p = .5;  q = 1-p
mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*q)
diff(pnorm(c(1.5,2.5), mu, sg))
## 0.3758935
```

*Reference:* J. Pitman: *Probability*, Springer, 1993 gives a more
sophisticated and accurate method of normal approximation than the
one in general use.

Comment: I got it now: $np > 9q$, and because $q \leq 1, np > 9$, or $np \geq 10$. If we dumb it down to $2$ standard deviations, $np \geq 5$. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Great! Wish I'd said that.